# Slowly Changing Dimension Wizard Historical Attribute Options No Start Date to choose from

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I'm in the historical attribute options tab of the slowly changing dimension wizard. I have the "use start and end dates to identify current and expired records," however when I click the drop down for both start and end date column, end date is my only option for both. How could this be? The start and end dates are the same data types in my dimension table datetime2(7)

I've looked at the dimension table data types to make sure there wasn't a data type issue that could potentially prevent SSIS from recognizing it as a usable field, but start and end date is the same exact data type. So I'm at a loss as to why end date is the only option to choose from.

My expected result is to be able to select the start date in my dimension table for my start date column.

Comment: I don't use the SCD Wizard and generally advise people not to. That said, you've checked the first place which is to ensure the data types are the same. The next thing I'd verify is the column's nullability. I don't see anything in the paltry documentation for [SCD Wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/historical-attribute-options-slowly-changing-dimension-wizard?view=sql-server-2017) but maybe you can spot something I'm not seeing.